# How can I send a "Message" back to a "Higher" Struct?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-iced

I currently have 2 files: **Main.rs** and **Connection.rs**.

**Connection.rs** currently contains the ability to `Send`, `Listen` and `Connect` to a `TcpStream`.

**Connection.rs**

```
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, WriteHalf, ReadHalf};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio::sync::Mutex;
use std::sync::Arc;
use iced_futures::futures;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum ConnMessage {
    Code(usize, String),
    Chat(usize, String),
    View(usize, String),
    None,
}


#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum ConnectionError {
    ConnectError(usize),
    SendError(usize),
    ReadError(usize),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Connection {
    pub write_stream: Arc<Mutex<WriteHalf<TcpStream>>>,
    pub read_stream: Arc<Mutex<ReadHalf<TcpStream>>>,
    pub loc: usize,
    pub code: String,
}

impl Connection {
    
    pub async fn connect(loc:usize) -> Result<Connection, ConnectionError> {
        
        let socket = TcpStream::connect("3.92.0.221:80").await.map_err(|_| ConnectionError::ConnectError(loc))?;
        
        let (rd, wr) = tokio::io::split(socket);
        
        let conn = Connection {
                    write_stream: Arc::new(Mutex::new(wr)),
                    read_stream: Arc::new(Mutex::new(rd)),
                    loc: loc,
                    code: String::from(""),
                };
        
        Ok( conn )
        
    }

    pub fn listen(conn: Connection) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut message = String::from("");
                loop {
                        let mut buf = [0u8; 16];
                let mut rd = conn.read_stream.lock().await;
                        rd.read(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
                
                // ASSUMPTION - Disconnected when Array is all 0s, i.e. a set of bytes that contained nothing is sent
                let mut disconnected = true;
                for i in buf.iter() {
                    if i != &0u8 {
                        disconnected = false;
                    }
                }
                if disconnected {
                    println!("Disconnected");
                }
                else {
                    let string_result = std::str::from_utf8(&buf).map_err(|_| ConnectionError::ReadError(conn.loc));
                    if string_result.is_ok() {
                        let string_contents = string_result.unwrap();
                        println!("conn.loc: {} -- Contents: {}", conn.loc, string_contents);

                        message += string_contents;
                        
                        // End of Message - Parse and Reset
                        if message.contains("\\.") {
                            println!("EOM");
                            message = message.replace("\\.", "");
                            // Send `message` to Message inside Main.rs
                            message = String::from("");
                            println!("Resetting Msg");
                        }
                        else {
                            println!("Not end of message");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        println!("String Result Error");
                    }
                }
                }
            });
        
        Ok(())
    }

    pub async fn send(connection: Connection, string: String) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
        let mut stream = connection.write_stream.lock().await;
        stream.write_all(string.as_bytes()).await.map_err(|_| ConnectionError::SendError(connection.loc))?;
        //println!("Code: {}", connection.code);
        Ok( () )
    }
}
```

**Main.rs** currently contains utilization of [Iced](https://github.com/hecrj/iced) to include a GUI that I created to establish connections on button presses.

```
use iced::{
    pane_grid, PaneGrid, Application, Settings, executor, Command, Container, Length, Element, 
    scrollable, button, Align, HorizontalAlignment, Column, Scrollable, Text, Button, Row,
    text_input, TextInput, 
};

use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, WriteHalf, ReadHalf};
//use tokio_util::codec::{BytesCodec, FramedRead, FramedWrite};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio::sync::Mutex;
//use futures::prelude::*;
use std::sync::Arc;

mod Connection;

pub fn main() -> iced::Result {
    ClientAdminGUI::run(Settings::default())
}

struct ClientAdminGUI {
    sessions_pane: pane_grid::State<ClientAdminSessionPaneContent>,
    chat_pane: pane_grid::State<ClientAdminChatPaneContent>, 
    image_viewer_pane: pane_grid::State<ClientAdminViewerPaneContent>,
    connections: Vec<Connection::Connection>,
    cur_connection: Option<Connection::Connection>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
enum Message {
    Session(Result<Connection::Connection, Connection::ConnectionError>), //Async Handler
    SendMessage,
    Send(Result<(), Connection::ConnectionError>), //Async Handler
    InputChanged(String),
    Button(usize, ButtonMessage),
    //None,
    UpdateCode(String),
    ReadConnMessage(Result<Connection::ConnMessage, ()>),
}

impl Application for ClientAdminGUI {
    type Message = Message;
    type Executor = executor::Default;
    type Flags = ();

    fn new(_flags: ()) -> (Self, Command<Message>) {
        let sessions_pane_content_value = ClientAdminSessionPaneContent::new();
        let (sessions_pane, _) = pane_grid::State::new(sessions_pane_content_value);
        let chat_pane_content_value = ClientAdminChatPaneContent::new();
        let (chat_pane, _) = pane_grid::State::new(chat_pane_content_value);
        let (image_viewer_pane, _) = pane_grid::State::new(ClientAdminViewerPaneContent::new());

        (
            ClientAdminGUI {
                sessions_pane,
                chat_pane,
                image_viewer_pane,
                connections: Vec::new(),
                cur_connection: None
            },
            Command::none(),
        )
    }

    fn title(&self) -> String {
        String::from("Client Admin GUI")
    }       

    fn update(&mut self, message: Message) -> Command<Message> {
        match message {
            Message::Session(Ok(result)) => {
                // result is a connection

                self.connections.push(result);

                // ...
                Connection::Connection::listen(Some(self.connections[self.connections.len()-1].clone()).unwrap());
            }
            ... //For all the rest of `Message`s 
        }
    }
}
```

Inside my `listen` function, I get the reply from a connection inside of there. But, I am not entirely sure how to feed that back to the application to be able to do some action with it.

**Question:**

How can I send the data I obtain from the `listen` function within **Connection.rs** back to my **main.rs** as a `Message` - say to my `Message::UpdateCode(String)` functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply needed to pass a `closure` as an argument to the function. From there, I had to ensure the lifetime was correct and it had the correct paramters.

You can accomplish this by passing a `generic` type then using `where` to set the exact type of the generic.

**Connection.rs**

```
use tokio::io::{AsyncReadExt, AsyncWriteExt, WriteHalf, ReadHalf};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;
use tokio::sync::Mutex;
use std::sync::Arc;
use iced_futures::futures;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum ConnMessage {
    Code(usize, String),
    Chat(usize, String),
    View(usize, String),
    None,
}


#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub enum ConnectionError {
    ConnectError(usize),
    SendError(usize),
    ReadError(usize),
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct Connection {
    pub write_stream: Arc<Mutex<WriteHalf<TcpStream>>>,
    pub read_stream: Arc<Mutex<ReadHalf<TcpStream>>>,
    pub loc: usize,
    pub code: String,
}

impl Connection {
    
    pub async fn connect(loc:usize) -> Result<Connection, ConnectionError> {
        
        let socket = TcpStream::connect("3.92.0.221:80").await.map_err(|_| ConnectionError::ConnectError(loc))?;
        
        let (rd, wr) = tokio::io::split(socket);
        
        let conn = Connection {
                    write_stream: Arc::new(Mutex::new(wr)),
                    read_stream: Arc::new(Mutex::new(rd)),
                    loc: loc,
                    code: String::from(""),
                };
        
        Ok( conn )
        
    }

    pub fn listen<F>(conn: Connection, read_message: F) where F: Fn(String, usize) + 'static + std::marker::Send {
        tokio::spawn(async move {
            let mut message = String::from("");
                loop {
                        let mut buf = [0u8; 16];
                let mut rd = conn.read_stream.lock().await;
                        rd.read(&mut buf).await.unwrap();
                
                // ASSUMPTION - Disconnected when Array is all 0s, i.e. a set of bytes that contained nothing is sent
                let mut disconnected = true;
                for i in buf.iter() {
                    if i != &0u8 {
                        disconnected = false;
                    }
                }
                if disconnected {
                    println!("Disconnected");
                }
                else {
                    let string_result = std::str::from_utf8(&buf).map_err(|_| ConnectionError::ReadError(conn.loc));
                    if string_result.is_ok() {
                        let string_contents = string_result.unwrap();
                        println!("conn.loc: {} -- Contents: {}", conn.loc, string_contents);

                        message += string_contents;
                        
                        // End of Message - Parse and Reset
                        if message.contains("\\.") {
                            println!("EOM");
                            message = message.replace("\\.", "");
                            read_message(message, conn.loc);
                            message = String::from("");
                            println!("Resetting Msg");
                        }
                        else {
                            println!("Not end of message");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        println!("String Result Error");
                    }
                }
                }
            });
    }

    pub async fn send(connection: Connection, string: String) -> Result<(), ConnectionError> {
        let mut stream = connection.write_stream.lock().await;
        stream.write_all(string.as_bytes()).await.map_err(|_| ConnectionError::SendError(connection.loc))?;
        Ok( () )
    }
}
```

**Main.rs** (Just relevant portion)

```
Connection::Connection::listen(Some(self.connections[self.connections.len()-1].clone()).unwrap(), 
                    (|string:String, loc:usize| {
                        println!("String is: {} -- loc: {}", string, loc);
                     }));
```